# Lusin Lipschitz approximation in BV and Sobolev space

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, soft-question, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Theorem 5.34 in *Functions of bounded variation* by L. Ambrosio, N. Fusco and D. Pallara states that

> Let $u \in [BV(\mathbb{R}^N)]^m$. Then there exists a constant $\kappa>0$ such that for every $u\in BV(\mathbb R^N)$ and $\lambda>0$ there exists a Lipschitz function $v_\lambda \in \mathrm{Lip}(\mathbb R^N)$ with Lipschitz constant $Lip(v_\lambda, \mathbb{R}^N) \le \kappa \lambda$ and 
>   $$
> |x\in \mathbb R^N : u(x)\ne v_\lambda(x)| \le \frac{\kappa}{\lambda} |Du|(\mathbb R^N),
> $$
>   where $\kappa$ depends on $N$ and $m$.

1. Can the result be made more precise using the Radon-Nikodym decomposition $Du = D^{a.c.}u + D^{j}u+D^{c}u$? In particular, what is the role of the singular part $D^{sing}u = D^j u + D^c u$?
2. What (improved) Lusin approximation result by Lipschitz function can be stated if $u \in [W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)]^m$ (with $1 \le p < \infty$)?

Answer (score 3):

With regards to Part 2, the paper [Improved $C^{k,\lambda}$ Approximation of Higher Order Sobolev Functions in Norm and Capacity](http://www.pitt.edu/~hajlasz/OriginalPublications/BojarskiHS-Improved-IndianaUnivMathJ-51-2002-507-540.pdf) by Bojarski, Hajlasz, and Strzelecki should be helpful. In particular, a Lusin approximation by smooth functions (originally proven by Michael and Ziemer in 1985) is stated as Theorem 1.1, and improved results are given as Theorems 1.2, 1.3, and 1.4.

Comment: Are the functions in the result you mention still globally Lipschitz?