# "Almost" absolute continuity of derivative of BV function if ${\rm Tr}\,D_Sf = 0$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, soft-question, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $f: \mathbb R^N \to \mathbb R^N$ be a $BV$ function. 
Suppose that $\mathrm{div} f$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure: $\operatorname{div} f \ll \mathcal L^N$. This implies, as seen in a [related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327761/bv-function-with-absolutely-continuous-divergence), 
that $${\rm Tr}\,D_Sf = 0.$$

Does it mean that $D_S f$ is *almost* absolutely continuous in some sense? What is the correct way to formalize this notion of "almost" absolute continuity?

Here is a more precise question:

- As mentioned in the question  [Lusin Lipschitz approximation in BV and Sobolev space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328207/lusin-lipschitz-approximation-in-bv-and-sobolev-space), $f$ is Lipschitz outside a small set (small with respect to the Lebesgue measure). Does ${\rm Tr} D_S f = 0$ imply that this set is "small" also with respect to the singular measure $D_S f$?

---

Related question are asked in the posts [BV function with absolutely continuous divergence](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327761/bv-function-with-absolutely-continuous-divergence) and [Role of absolute continuity of divergence of BV function in proof of renormalization property](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327789/role-of-absolute-continuity-of-divergence-of-bv-function-in-proof-of-renormaliza)